# Transfering big sized files between external hard drives and MacBook

Tags: macos, macbook-air

I want to know how to transfer big sized file or folder(e.g. 11 GB or 15GB) between external hard drives and Mac. I know there is a file transferring limit and how much GB is allowed to transfer? I downloaded HD Blu-ray movie(12.8GB) to my MacBook Air and I want to store in my external hard disk. But I can't transfer this file. Please advise me what should I do.

Comment: What kind of limit are you referring too?

Comment: I think over 10GB is not allowed to transfer.

Comment: Why would you think so?

Comment: I transferred 12.8GB file form my mac to external hard disk. Then, the message came out. File size is too big to transfer and I can't.

Comment: Well do you have free space on your external hard disk? Also, what file system is your external disk using?

Comment: There is over 400GB of free space. File system is FAT32.

Comment: @Newbie - This limit isn't imposed by OS X.  So there must be some other reason your getting this message.

Comment: sorry about file system. It's FAT32. I was wrong with another one for windows.

Comment: Well there you go, FAT32 has maximum file size of 4 GB. You should reformat it to NTFS or exFAT. I suggest exFAT because newer versions of OS X have full read/write capabilites while for NTFS by default you have only read only. exFAT is also supported on Windows.

Comment: FAT32 has a file-size limit. If you're only using it on a mac you should reformat it to hfs+, unless you're sharing it with Windows machines, in which case you might want to use exFAT. Use Disk Utitlity (/Applications/Utilities/Disk Utility) and choose erase.  You will lose everything on the disk though so copy it somewhere first. Edit: snap!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It probably depends mostly on the filesystem you are using on the external drive.

Check the filesystem of the external drive and have a look here to determine the maximum file size it could take.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_file_systems#Limits